# Elastic Search aggregation starting with

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation

Is there a way to add a filter to a `terms` aggregation so I get just the ones starting with certain string?

I'm starting from here:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "address": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "address"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`include` or `exclude` parameters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_2):

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "address": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "address",
        "include": "Main.*"     <-- add this
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a problem with this solution. If there is an address "Even green terrace",  it will return "even"", "green" and "terrace", but not the full value. How can I make sure that it just returns the full text of the value?

Comment: Try to use the `address.raw`or `address.keyword` field if you have one. Otherwise, you'll have to change your mapping and reindex your data.